# Invoking the button from other view controller

Tags: ios, uibutton

How to invoke (fake event of) the button which is in a second view controller when button in first view controller is clicked?

I can fake the event for a button which is in the same view controller by doing this:

```
- (IBAction)first:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"this is second");
}

- (IBAction)second:(id)sender {
     [self.first sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];   // works
}
```

But if the button is in a different view controller, I'm not able to fake it:

```
- (IBAction)first:(id)sender {
   SecondViewController *SecondView = [[ViewController alloc] init];
   [SecondView.button sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; // doesnt work

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your 2nd VC is owned by your 1st VC, then

a) Add a property like this to a class extension of your `FirstViewController`, for example:

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController()
// Be aware of retain cycles.
@property (nonatomic, retain) SecondViewController *secondVC;
@end
```

b) When you create the SecondViewController, store it in the property we just created:

```
// Change this if you're not using a Storyboard.
self.secondVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                           bundle:nil]
          instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
```

c) Add a method to your `SecondViewController`:

```
- (void)clickMyButton:(id)sender {
     [self.myButton sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

d) Make it happen from your `FirstViewController`:

```
[self.secondVC clickMyButton:self];
```

If my 1st assumption is not correct, you still can do steps A, B, and D. Step B changes a bit: You have to set `self.secondVC` with the existing instance that was created somewhere else.

Comment: 1st view controller has search bar , on click on search bar ill get the popover(2nd view controller) and keyboard(search bar keyboard) , 
popover is having SEARCH button , which will go for 3rd view controller(push).

now on click on search key of keyboard ,2nd view SEARCH button must invoke

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to execute the action associated to your `search` button when you press the "search" key on the keyboard. Is that correct? If yes, you just have to implement `- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar;` in your popover, and set `self.searchBar.delegate = self` to make the `UISearchBar` notify your controller when the search key is pressed.

Comment: exactly . but search key belongs to 1st view controller, 

search button belongs to 2nd view controller

Comment: So implement the `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` to do `[self.secondVC clickMyButton:self]` on your `1st` controller, set the `UISearchBar` delegate accordingly, and implement the steps I wrote in the answer.

Comment: I'd split the task into:
1) Try to get the 1st controller notified about the key press;
2) Try to make the 1st controller click the button on the 2nd controller;
3) Put it all together;
4) Test everything;
5) Coffee time;

Comment: sorry, button method will execute(bcz im getting nslog) , but im not getting 3rd view, so only i thought of faking the button by sending action

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're saying.